# How to interpolate .csv file with the spectra values to have a spectrum with more points in Python?

Tags: python, csv, interpolation

In the .csv file the 1st column represents the spectra wave number and the subsequent columns represent the respective absorbance values for each strawberry sample. Wavenumbers begin with 899.327 and ends with 1802.564. They are separated by 3.86. I have to create spectra with wavenumbers are separated by 3.86/2, 3.86/4 and 3.86/8. I have 632 NON-Strawberry and 351 Strawberry spectra columns. For the interpolation I can use scipy interpolate but I could not managed to do it. [image: asdf]